# With free running loops of different lengths, how do I calculate what bar a loop will be on after X bars?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I have a loop A of 2 bars, Loop B of three bars, and Loop C of 4 bars, What is the formula to work out what bar each of Loops A B + C are on after say 64 bars? 100 bars or a given number of bars? It doesn't have to be in the musical context of bars and loops, It could be fence panels of different sizes. I need to use it in a musical context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for remainders after division.

For example, your loop $B$ of $3$ bars goes $1,2,3,1,2,3,\dots$ where $1$ is the first bar.

After $0$ bars, $B$ is on bar $1$ (i.e. when we start we're at the beginning of bar $1$).

After $1$ bar, $B$ is on bar $2$.

After $2$ bars, $B$ is on bar $3$.

After $3$ bars, $B$ is on bar $1$.  It's just as though nothing had happened.

After every $3$ bars, we're back to the start. After $64$ bars: well, $64=3\times21+1$, so all those $3$'s do nothing and we're at the same place as if we did $1$ bar (i.e. we're on bar 2). After $74$ bars, $74=3\times24+2$, so it's like doing $2$ bars (i.e. we're on bar $3$). After $99=33\times3$ bars, it's like we did nothing (i.e. we're on bar $1$).

Similarly, for your loop $A$ of $2$ bars, after $64=32\times2$ bars we're on bar $1$ (no remainder, same as doing nothing), after $74=37\times2$ we're on bar $1$, and after $99=49\times2+1$ we're on bar $2$ (remainder 1 means same as after $1$ bar).

For your loop $C$ of $4$ bars, after $64=16\times4$ bars we're on bar $1$ (no remainder, same as doing nothing), after $74=18\times4+2$ we're on bar $3$ (remainder 2 means same as after $2$ bars), and after $99=24\times4+3$ we're on bar $4$ (remainder 3 means same as after $3$ bars).

In elementary school this idea is expressed as division-after-remainder. In higher study it's called modulo arithmetic. In computer programming languages there's usually a function called 'modulo' which gives you what you want, e.g. in C or Python or Perl the expression `1+47%6` tells you where a loop of $6$ bars is after $47$ bars have passed.